# Need a regex pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I'm am looking for regex pattern to validate numbers where the numbers can be greater than for but not lowers  minus than (-50) !

Example:

```
( (stop),-50, -3, -2, -1, 0 1, 2, 3...50, 51, 52... so on...)
```

can anyone please help?

FYI using following validation method

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid"
});
$("#SeatOnlyVFR").validate({
    rules: {


        DayMarkup: {
            required: true,
            pattern: /^[1-9][0-9]?$|^100$/,
        },

        NightMarkup: {
            required: true,

        }

    },

    submitHandler: function (form) {
       Markup()
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Regex probably isn't the way to go here.  Just use JavaScript's numeric comparison operators to check numbers.

Comment: I agree but some times we need to specify pattern and can not execute code like in this example. One more exampe like this is webpack loader configuration section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
/^-?[1-4]?[0-9]$|^-50$|^1?[5-9]?[0-9]$/
```

Some times we need to specify pattern and can not execute code like in this example. One more exampe like this is webpack loader configuration section. So we need to write pattern which work like equation.

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for the solution, and the solution works fine in my workspace environment. And could you please guide me through to enhance the code where it drives beyond 97, 98, 99 ... and further in your solution please well it doesn't execute beyond 99, and could you please help me to reach up to number where it generates higher than 99 unlimited manner. Example:  ( (stop),-50, -3, -2, -1, 0 1, 2, 3...50, 51, 52...99, 100, 101, 102... and so on...). Thanks you !

Comment: Try this: /^-?[1-4]?[0-9]$|^-50$|^[0-9][0-9]*$/